# SublimeText 2 is changing a 0 into date when tabbing

Tags: mysql, sublimetext2

I have a .sql file I'm editing with SublimeText 2. The file is to be used to insert data into a database for testing purposes. I am trying to get the whitespace adjusted so that making changes to the data on the fly is easier. When attempting to use Tab when the cursor is between a '0' and a comma (,), Sublime 2 is changing the '0' into a date.

Example:

```
INSERT INTO `Table_Name`
(`ID`   , `First`   , `Last`    , `IsAdmin`, `JoinDate`)
VALUES
(`999`  , `John`    , `Smith`   , 0, 2013-05-09);
```

I then Tab:

```
INSERT INTO `Table_Name`
(`ID`   , `First`   , `Last`    , `IsAdmin`, `JoinDate`)
VALUES
(`999`  , `John`    , `Smith`   , 2013-05-09, 2013-05-09);
```

Is there something I'm doing wrong in Sublime or is this just a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's just the closest match of `0` SublimeText found in the current project. ST keeps track of almost any symbol/text/number you highlight in all the files you browse in a project and uses them for autocomplete.

In case of me, writing `0` and pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd> autocompleted to `00148800`, because in a file I opened, there was this line I highlighted -

```
"salt": "0.00148800 1367514464",
```

In your case, you have written `2013-05-09` before. And hence this.

You can [turn this off](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/2/auto_complete.html), or just press space.